# Add to list if value is not null

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I have the function that could return null value:

```scala
def func(arg: AnyRef): String = {
...
}
```

and I want to add  the result to list, if it is not null:

```scala
...
val l = func(o)
if (l != null)
  list :+= l
....
```

or

```scala
def func(arg: AnyRef): Option[String] = {
...
}
```

```scala
...
func(o).filter(_ != null).map(f => list :+= f)
...
```

But it looks too heavy.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Avoid the use of `null` in Scala - it really only exists for interoperability with Java. Use `Option` (and `Some`, `None`) instead.

Comment: Yes, Option looks nice, but my solution still looks too heavy.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can simply append the option to the list. This is because an `Option` can be treated as an `Iterable` (empty for`None`, with one single element for`Some`) thanks to the implicit conversion `Option.option2Iterable`.

So for the option variant (second version of `func`) just do:

```
list ++= func(o)
```

For the other variant (first version of `func`) you can first convert the return value of `func` to an Option using `Option.apply` (will turn `null` to `None` or else wrap the value with `Some`) and then do like above. Which gives:

```
list ++= Option(func(o))
```

Comment: You should be aware that you're relying on a special behavior in the `Option` factory in which `null` becomes `None` while non-`null` values yield `Some(value)`.

Comment: I know that, and I believe that my answer made it clear (citing myself: "using Option.apply (will turn null to Some or else wrap the value with Some)"). In addition, this behaviour is not an accident, it is properly documented in the scaladoc for `Option.apply`

Comment: Oops, now I see that I made a typo, I said "will turn null into Some" instead of "will turn null into None", silly me. Is that what confused you? In any case, this is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

First you should indicate that the function may/may not return a value where the return value is wrapped in `Some` or `None` is returned

```
def func(arg: AnyRef): Option[String] = {
    //  ...
    Some(value) orElse None
}
```

With a list from func(0) `val list = func(0) collect {case Some(x) => x}` which takes only values which are defined using collect.