# I need advice on Play's Json and elegant Option handling in the Writes trait

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I have a "style" or "effective scala" type of question here:
I have a "FeatureCheck" class which I need to serialize into a Json in Play framework.

```
case class FeatureCheck(val result: Option[Boolean], val missing: Option[Array[String]], val error: Option[String])
```

I am serializing it using my own "writes" but my code looks a lot like Java code. I would like to serialize each option in the check object only if it is defined (the final object should not have any empty values).

```
def writes(check: FeatureCheck): JsValue = {
  val builder = Seq.newBuilder[(String, JsValue)]
  if (check.error.isDefined) {
    builder += "error" -> JsString(check.error.get)
  }
  if (check.missing.isDefined) {
    builder += "missing" -> Json.toJson(check.missing.get)
  }
  if (check.result.isDefined) {
    builder += "result" -> JsBoolean(check.result.get)
  }
  JsObject(builder.result)
}
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to do this without those ugly if-then, or even removing the builder for the sequence.

Thanks for any help or comment given.

### Clarrifications:

Let's say I want to just send result = true I want the resulting Json to be:

```
{"result":true}
```

and NOT

```
{
    "result": true,
    "error": null,
    "missing": []
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you can simply append an option to a seq (see [Add to list if value is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438021/add-to-list-if-value-is-not-null/14438344#14438344)), you can do what you want rather elegantly:

```
type JsField = (String, JsValue)
def writes(check: FeatureCheck): JsValue = {
  JsObject(
    Seq[JsField]() ++
    check.error.map("error" -> JsString(_)) ++
    check.missing.map("missing" -> Json.toJson(_)) ++
    check.result.map("result" -> JsBoolean(_))    
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can skip the extra `isDefined` check, it will only check if the option value is `Some`. The `getOrElse` will perform the same thing for `Option` in scala.

This is a somewhat simpler version.

```
def writes(check: FeatureCheck): JsValue = {
  val builder = Seq.newBuilder[(String, JsValue)]
  builder += "error" -> JsString(check.error.getOrElse(""))
  builder += "missing" -> Json.toJson(check.missing.getOrElse({ Array[String]() }))
  builder += "result" -> JsBoolean(check.result.getOrElse(false))
  JsObject(builder.result)
}
```

And this may be considered even simpler.

```
def writes(check: FeatureCheck): JsValue = JsObject(
  List(
    "error" -> JsString(check.error.getOrElse("")),
    "missing" -> Json.toJson(check.missing.getOrElse({ Array[String]() })),
    "result" -> JsBoolean(check.result.getOrElse(false))
  )
)
```

---

**EDIT**

If you don't want the properties added if they are not present then this is more elegant I guess:

```
def writes(check: FeatureCheck): JsValue = JsObject(
  List(
    check.error.map("error" -> JsString(_)),
    check.missing.map("missing" -> Json.toJson(_)),
    check.result.map("result" -> JsBoolean(_))
  ).flatten
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't result in {"error":null, "missing":[], "result":true} rather than {"result":true} ?

Comment: @le_douard Ok you don't want to write the property at all if it is not defined? Then why did you use `getOrElse` in the first place?

Comment: sorry that getOrElse is mostly to make my IDE happy ... which could be misleading, I apologize. I corrected my questions ... sorry again

Answer (score 0):

Another option you have is to filter out null fields after Json object creation, I use the following util method:

```
  def filterOutNullFields(jsonObject:JsObject) : JsObject =  {
    jsonObject.fields.foldLeft(jsonObject)((jsonObjectAcc , tupleKeyValue) => {
      if (tupleKeyValue._2.isInstanceOf[JsObject]) {
        val innerJsonObject = filterOutNullFields(tupleKeyValue._2.as[JsObject])
        jsonObjectAcc - tupleKeyValue._1 + (tupleKeyValue._1, innerJsonObject)
      }
      else {
        if (tupleKeyValue._2.equals(JsNull)) {
          jsonObjectAcc - tupleKeyValue._1
        } else {
          jsonObjectAcc
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

You can just use it like:

```
val featureCheckJson = Json.toJson(featureCheck)
val featureCheckJsonWithoutNullFields = filterOutNullFields(featureCheckJson.as[JsObject])
```